# Google Maps API for both localhost & production server, as of April 2019

Tags: google-maps, api-key

**TLDR**

My code works fine on my laptop when accessed as `file://<path>/index.html`, but neither on my laptop with an Apache server running when accessed as `http://<path>/index.html`, nor on my real (production) server. I see no errors on the console, but the map is just a grey rectangle.

[Update] I moved to [LeafletJS](https://leafletjs.com/) shortly after asking this question, and recommend others to do so too.

---

It has been a few years since I coded any Google Maps applications.

It seems that, as of last year, it is now necessary to have an API key, by providing it with credit card details, and to provide it with each API call.

Unfortunately, there is ***a lot of*** of information about this, much/most of it out of date and/or contradictory.

Can anyone point to the canonical guide, preferably with screenshots, of how to configure this?

I wish to draw a map, and add some makers, which will require reverse geocoding, such that I provide a street address and convert it to lat/long in order to place the markers.

Sounds simple enough, but which of the many thousands of "helpful" site has gotten it right?

For instance, what seems to be [the current Google help page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) speaks of

> From the  Navigation menu, select APIs & Services > Credentials.
> On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key

But I can't even see that menu option :-(

---

**[Update]** If it helps any, the error message in the developer console said :

> Geocoding Service: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

---

**[Update]** I am trying to access the API like this

```
<script src="maps.google.com/maps/api/…>
```

and

```
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + comapnyLocation +'&key=XXXX';
```

$http.get(url)

**[Update++]** in the developer console, I see a bunch of errors along the lines of:

> aliextension.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/JAR.png:1 GET https://aliextension.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/JAR.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have no idea what `aliextension` is, nor does it appear in my code (maybe in some minified JS?)

Ok, it is something to do with AliExpress (Ali Baba). I removed it & the timeout messages go away, but I still have problems.

If I load the `index.html` into Chrome as a `file://`, then it works just fine. But, if I load it `as http://, where I have a Xampp Apache server running, the map box remains grey, although I see no error messages. The same thing happens on my real server :-(

Comment: Did you go to the [google api console](https://console.developers.google.com/)? 
 The link on the documentation goes to: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/#get-started

Comment: I have selected "no restrictions". Now, after reboot, it won't work for `localhost` :-(   I see no errors or warning in the developer console

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like I need to prove ownership fo my domain, then associate teh domain wih the API key. I posted [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1420304/how-to-verify-domain-ownership-for-google-maps-api-using-cpanel) about that - but maybe I am mistaken that that is necessary

Comment: I updated the question to show the error message. I will look into that & see if it provides any help

Comment: How are you using the key in your request?

Comment: ` <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=XXXX"></script>` and `var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + comapnyLocation +'&key=XXXX';
                 

                 $http.get(url)`

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include that information (and add a [mcve] that would demonstrates the issue with your key)?

Comment: If I replace `comapnyLocation` with the string "New York, NY", in the posted query, I get the response: `"error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid."`  If I change "XXXX" to a valid key, I get a over query error (with a key that is over the query limit), what response do you get?  Or is this a google maps Javascript API v3 issue?

Comment: See udated question. Thanks for asking that +1

Comment: That sounds like a CSS issue.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page should be your starting point:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
it helps you working with Google map javascript API.

To embedded a google map to your website read the overview page in the above link.

To add markers to your google map read this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

To do reverse geocoding read this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

That all i need to work with google map. I think you can do the same too.

Comment: Well, the demo HTML from the first page works, so I think that we can rule out an API key issue - which I was fairly sure it was - and I probably have an error in my code somewhere. although it is too large to post

Comment: I moved to [LeafletJS](https://leafletjs.com/) shortly after asking this question, and recommend others to do so too.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for this is quite likely an [API key restriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey).

In order to permit these host-names or IP addresses, you have to:

a) go to the [credentials panel](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and select the according project, then click on "Api key".

b) there you can loosen the restrictions, for `HTTP referrers` (for web-sites)

... or for `IP addresses` (in case these are server-side requests).

Comment: It says `Application restrictions


None` - that should be ok, right?

Comment: @Mawg you need to select `HTTP referrers (web sites)` and then add your URLs there... else anybody who finds this key can use it and you are being billed for it (possibly it won't even work unless restricting it). also check "API restrictions", if the Maps API is indeed available with this key (there the default "none" setting isn't that bad as it is for "Application restrictions").